# Parse string into date with c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Is there a way to parse the  following strings into date without splitting it wrt **-** character?

```
25-11-2014
5-6-2013
3-10-2012
```

I was using the following code on another case. However due to missing leading zeros, it did not work.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("06-05-2016", "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact("06-05-2016", "d-M-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Your code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("06-05-2016", "dd-MM-yyyy", ...);
```

explicitly says "look for a 2-digit day and month".  If you want single digit months/days (without a leading zero), just change the format string...

```
DateTime.ParseExact("06-05-2016", "d-M-yyyy", ...)
```

That will allow you to use days 1-31 instead of 01-31, and months 1-12 instead of months 01-12.

Answer (score 3):

**Consider Your Formatting String**

[Formatting strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) are very stringent with regards to what they expect to come in. If you indicate that you'll be receiving a two-digit date, then it will expect a leading zero.

As a result of this, you can consider changing your formatting string to one that would accept single character dates and months, which would satisfy all of the example inputs that you provided [as seen here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PdidPO) :

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "d-M-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Handling Multiple Formats**

Additionally, the [`DateTime.ParseExact()` method has an overload that accepts multiple formatting strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx) that would allow to to essentially define multiple formats that your date might be in :

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input, new []{ "d-M-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy" }, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```